# Getting shortest path between 2 nodes in quickgraph

Tags: c#, shortest-path, a-star, quickgraph

i want to ask if there is any way to generate the shortest path from node A to node B
without generating the shortest paths to all the other nodes (stop when node B is in the examined set)
with A-star in QuickGraph.

I want to plug QuickGraph into a game and thus generating all the paths is not allowed from the time
limitations the environment imposes.

Any other suggestions to solve my problem in C# are welcome

Thanks in advance,
Xtapodi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickgraph 3.3 has a built-in implementation of A* :

```
QuickGraph.Algorithms.ShortestPath.AStarShortestPathAlgorithm<TVertex,TEdge>
```

which version of quickgraph are you using ?

Comment: I have version 3.6 but i don't see how to set target node? Maybe i could do it by handling events, but this is possible for Dijkstra. Am I missing something?

Comment: @watbywbarif: If your `A*` algorithm instance is, say, `astar`, just call `astar.Compute(startNode);` and then call `var distance = astar.Distances[destNode];` to get the distance between `startNode` and `destNode`

Comment: but this will calculate distance to all nodes in graph, from this question it seams that I can start algorithm to calculate until it reaches targetNode and then stop.

Comment: @watbywbarif: I answered to you here --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/8617637/316644

Answer (score 2):

How we can get full path instead of distance?